# php search engine multyple keywords/tags

Tags: php, mysql, search-engine

Can anyone suggest me a database structure or some explicit tutorial for creating a search engine with multiple keywords?

The keywords have to match multiple tags not to be part of a string (like an article title)

example:
I type in the search field the words: php mysql database and the script should return all entries with this tags.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

MyISAM has full text search, which basically allows you to search for strings, and returns the results in order of relevance ([more info](http://www.databasejournal.com/sqletc/article.php/1578331/Using-Fulltext-Indexes-in-MySQL---Part-1.htm)). I think that could be just what you're looking for!

Comment: Is this the only way? I would prefer some int index based search.